# Resource compilation failed :Duplicate value for resource 'attr/cornerSize'

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, build.gradle, android-resources

I have tried multiple ways to remove this error but nothing works. I also deleted cache folder, but after generating build, the same files and errors are re-created. Material-1.4.0 library is also okay. I have even tried shifting from latest to previous buildToolVersion i.e.30 but again it didn't work.

> Task :app:mergeCashbackDeals_noDebugResources FAILED
> /home/noor/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6a20edf6a6be96f7c4e1069bdca612ca/transformed/material-1.4.0-beta01/res/values/values.xml:4078:4: Duplicate value for resource 'attr/cornerSize' with config 'DEFAULT' and product ''. Resource was previously defined here: /home/noor/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6a20edf6a6be96f7c4e1069bdca612ca/transformed/material-1.4.0-beta01/res/values/values.xml:3928:4: .

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeCashbackDeals_noDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.

Comment: Have you created the `attr` file in the `values` file?

Comment: @MDev I haven't created attr file. It was working fine previously. I have made multiple changes on gradle and updated studio as well. Later on I have faced this issue and still facing it. Nothing has worked yet.